# I'm getting problem to hide my button using this javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want my button to hide after a certain time; I've tried every idea I had, but I still can't get over the problem.

```js
function myTimer() {
  var now = Date().now;
  var startTime = new Date();
  var endTime = new Date();

  startTime.setHours(11, 55, 0);
  endTime.setHours(21, 51, 0);

  var button = document.getElementById("verse1");

  if ((now < startTime || now > endTime) && button.style.visibility != "hidden")
    button.style.visibility = "hidden";
  else if (button.style.visibility != "visible")
    button.style.visibility = "visible";
}

window.setInterval(myTimer, 500);
```

```html
<button id="verse1">hello</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Date.now()`; `Date().now` is undefined.

```js
var now = Date.now();
```

Comment: This should probably just be closed as a typo.